# Reserva temporária

Tags: php, mysql

estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou criando uma aplicação de reservas e assim que um usuário clicar num produto para reservar, esse produto deve ser retirado da lista dos disponíveis temporariamente para que ele finalize a reserva. Se ele não finalizar em 5 minutos, esse produto volta a ficar disponível.

Consegui realizar essa reserva prévia fazendo um update na coluna 'status' do produto, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer ele voltar a disponibilidade após 5 minutos.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode utilizar um Cron para atualizar novamente todos os itens que tiveram seu status marcados para reserva e não foram confirmados nos últimos 5 minutos e voltar eles para o status de disponível. Inclua o seu código à pergunta.

Comment: Eu utilizaria um evento agendado no mysql que rodasse a cada 5 minutos e faria uma validação de acordo com a hora de agendamento e a hora atual.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `EVENT` do `MySQL`, para isso primeiramente precisa ativar o recurso no seu banco de dados:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Criar o evento:

```
CREATE EVENT mudar_status
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE tabela_status
SET status = 1
WHERE status = 0
```

Comment: E se a compra for realizada, como cancela o evento?

Comment: Isso vc determina no WHERE, quando for feita a reserva, por exemplo, vc coloca um status = 2, e quando confirmada status = 0, entende? Mas ai vc altera ali, antes de criar o evento, qual status é o da reserva